# Is it possible to work on react using JSX, without a node server and using create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx, create-react-app

I'm in a big trouble, I'm a really a noob on React and in the company I work on I propose to code a project that was on pure Javascript to update it to ReactJS, 
In this project I can't use a node server And I have been coding React without JSX as shown on this page:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html

it's working... but as soon as the project gets more complicated, then gets more complicated to code...

I though I have found a solution to work on JSX without a Node server, that is to code with create-react-app:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

I can code on JSX and then run the command "npm run build" and it generates all the React code in the build folder, and then I tried to run build/index.html, but it doesn't load anything, any idea If what I'm trying to do is it possible?

Comment: What is in the build folder after you run npm run build?  Does build/index.html exist, and if so what code is there?

Comment: When I type "npm run build" this appears:

  48.12 KB  build\static\js\main.9fdf0e48.js
  288 B     build\static\css\main.cacbacc7.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

  "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build

It generates the js files, but when I open the index,html in the browser the page doesn't load anything

Answer (score 0):

Once you get things working the right way, I highly recommend you use `.jsx`. You can hook a frontend to any backend you want. Don't you have an existing `index.html` file that you can import your React entry file into?

`create-react-app` has its own way of doing things. If you're updating an existing codebase, you should probably be starting from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

You need a server to host your dist/index.html site. This requires you to build a simple server with either node or some other back end programming language.  I believe the reason it works whenever you use create-react-app it is because when you `npm start` create-react-app runs a simple server to host your application.  Why can't you use a node server?

Comment: I just don't know if that is possible, the backend was made with legacy software, I mean the backend It's working on webforms and I just don't want to touch the backend part...